# How to prevent Gradle from checking/updating certain dependencies?

Tags: gradle

Due to certain framework updates and changes, I need to utilize a SNAPSHOT of the LibGDX framwwork in my app. As a result, new updates are pushed out frequently, sometimes with unwanted changes at the moment.

I'd like to continue to be able to have Gradle update/download new dependency updates for my projects, but would like if I could exclude certain dependencies (LibGDX) from ever changing from what's already downloaded locally.

This shows what I mean:

[image]

Can't find anything on Google about it. A nice tag like "offline" just for those few dependencies would be basically what I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gradle dependencies --write-locks
```

This will effectively lock all resolvable configurations that have locking enabled (including your situation). You can also have a look at whats been locked here.

```
gradle/dependency-locks/compileClasspath.lockfile
```

This may need a more recent version of Gradle than recommended but I have found myself on my project that you can bump up gradle. You can find out more described here

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html

Answer (score 0):

Not changing the value of `$gdxVersion` should suffice to accomplish this behavior. IntelliJ also offers the annotation `//noinspection GradleDependency`, which will not mark outdated versions in yellowish (to be placed in the line above the dependency reference); but this is barely cosmetic.

You could also add these libraries directly into the project, to have them available offline
...but these repositories always keep the old versions, so there is nothing to worry about.

That Exif interface & annotations should be updated to AndroidX, because it will clash (or it will require the Jetifier, which could otherwise be ditched). It might speed up the build time a little, when there's one less resource-intense task to process.

Comment: Thing is like I mentioned it's a snapshot version, so while $gdxVersion doesn't change, the library is updated a few times a week and thus keeps getting re-downloaded. So basically what you mentioned with the `//noinspection GradleDependency` would be ideal, if only it weren't just cosmetic. PS thx @ the AndroidX note

Comment: If it is a snapshot, the only option to ensure reproducible builds is to add the files. While in general, it might be recommend to use stable release versions instead of snapshots. AAR can be added into a local `flatDir` repository. When commenting out the online one, it will have no other choice, but to use them.